# Matplotlib Patches - Circle appears to be an Ellipse

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create and plot a grid of hexagons. To do so, I have defined the following function:

```
def create_hexagon(center):
        INRADIUS = 0.5
        CIRCUMRADIUS = INRADIUS / math.cos(math.radians(30))
        pt1 = [center[0], center[1] + CIRCUMRADIUS]
        pt4 = [center[0], center[1] - CIRCUMRADIUS]
        pt2 = [center[0] + INRADIUS, center[1]+CIRCUMRADIUS/2]
        pt6 = [center[0] - INRADIUS, center[1]+CIRCUMRADIUS/2]
        pt3 = [center[0] + INRADIUS, center[1]-CIRCUMRADIUS/2]
        pt5 = [center[0] - INRADIUS, center[1]-CIRCUMRADIUS/2]
        points = [pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, pt6]
        return points
```

I know, there is a lot of geometry happenning here, but I am pretty sure these 6 points are described correctly in dependance of the center point. If you can think of a nicer way than describing each of the 6 points individually, pls let me know! 
What I do next is, I loop through a list that contains all the center points. I, then, go ahead and plot a hexagon around each center:

```
for pt in centers:
    points = create_hexagon(pt)
    hexagon = plt.Polygon(points, fill=None, edgecolor='k')
    plt.gca().add_patch(hexagon)
    circle = plt.Circle(pt, 0.5 / math.cos(math.radians(30)), fill=None)
    plt.gca().add_patch(circle)
```

As my plot does not seem to be correct, I have drawn a circle around every center as well. And the circle does not appear to be a circle, but rather an ellipse:
[image]
It is more apparent, when zooming in:
[image]

Why don't I get circles?

Comment: It looks like a circle to me, accordingly to the scales at least.

Comment: Mind the scales. The vertical scale extends less than the horizontal one. Hence the circle in data units does not appear circular in screen units. If that is important for you, make the scales equal, e.g. `plt.gca().set_aspect("equal")`

Comment: aha! I think, it is the x-axis that has a different scale than my y-axis! ...

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are okay, the only bad thing is the scale (x axis not graduated as the y axis).

Just add this :

```
plt.xlim(0, 4.5)
plt.ylim(0, 3.5)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.show()
```